# How to struct an object to represent a list of topics?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm coding at C# and **I'm trying to make an OOP representation of a list of topics**. I tried countless approaches but I still not being able to reach the desired result.

I want to make a method later that will output it like:

```
1) Text
  1.1) Text
2) Text
  2.1) Text
  2.2) Text
    2.2.1) Text
    2.2.2) Text
  2.3) Text
3) Text
  3.1) Text
```

When needed to get a single topic, I would like to create a method calling my object like:

```cs
private string GetSingleTopic()
{
  return $"{Topic.Numerator}) {Topic.Text}"
}
```

### EXAMPLES

#### Example 1

I would be able to instantiate the object such as:

```cs
var variable = new TopicObject
{
  "TitleA",
  "TitleB",
  "TitleC" 
}
/* --- OUTPUT ---
1) TitleA
2) TitleB
3) TitleC
   --- OUTPUT --- */
```

#### Example 2

Be able to instantiate the object such as:

```cs
var variable = new TopicObject
{
  "TitleA",
  "TitleB",
  "TitleC":
  {
    "TitleD":
    {
      "TitleE"
    },
    "TitleF":
    {
      "TitleG",
      "TitleH"
    }
  }
}
/* --- OUTPUT ---
1) TitleA
2) TitleB
3) TitleC
  3.1) TitleD
    3.1.2) TitleE
  3.2) TitleF
    3.2.1) TitleG
    3.2.2) TitleH
   --- OUTPUT --- */
```

### My Approach

This, was one of my many approaches. I couldn't use it because I can't initialize the inner topic List in the way i mentioned, like an hierarchy.
But the structure is pretty similar to what I want to achieve so I decided to put here as an example.

```cs
public abstract class TopicBase
{
    public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; } // optional

    protected TopicBase() { Topics = new List<Topic>(); }
    protected TopicBase(List<Topic> topics) { Topics = topics; }

    public TopicBase AddTopic(string topicText)
    {
        var test = new Topic(topicText);
        Topics.Add(test);
        return this;
    }
}

public class Topic
{
    public Topic(string text)
    {
        Numerator++;
        Text = text;
    }
    public int Numerator { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
}

public class TopicLevel1 : TopicBase { }
public class TopicLevel2 : TopicBase { }
public class TopicLevel3 : TopicBase { }
```

Comment: I don't believe you can achieve your "example 2"... And " I couldn't use it because of many reasons" is not a good explanation of the problem you are facing. If that is not homework and you are pulling initialization example out of thin air consider just sticking with what is possible without any special tricks. If it is homework - re-read it carefully and check with the teacher if you understood it correctly. In either case [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: I don't think your issue is `oop`, `logic` or `code-structure` I'd remove all of these tags. It's more of a data-structure problem. I'd advise you trying to tackle problem one piece at a time, and try to come up with a basic implementation for just a basic case. Implement first a data structure that would process flat list `Topic A`, `Topic B`, `Topic C` and then refactor from there. But your question doesn't show any attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by defining a data structure that can hold the topics:

```
public class Topics<T> : List<Topic<T>> { }

public class Topic<T> : List<Topic<T>>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public Topic(T value, params Topic<T>[] children)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        if (children != null)
            this.AddRange(children);
    }
}
```

That allows us to write this code:

```
var topics = new Topics<string>()
{
  new Topic<string>("TitleA"),
  new Topic<string>("TitleB"),
  new Topic<string>("TitleC",
    new Topic<string>("TitleD",
        new Topic<string>("TitleE")),
    new Topic<string>("TitleF",
        new Topic<string>("TitleF"),
        new Topic<string>("TitleH")))
};
```

That matches your "Example 2" data.

To output the result we add two `ToOutput` methods.

To `Topics<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToOutput(Func<T, string> format)
    => this.SelectMany((t, n) => t.ToOutput(0, $"{n + 1}", format));
```

To `Topic<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToOutput(int depth, string prefix, Func<T, string> format)
{
    yield return $"{new string(' ', depth)}{prefix}) {format(this.Value)}";
    foreach (var child in this.SelectMany((t, n) => t.ToOutput(depth + 1, $"{prefix}.{n + 1}", format)))
    {
        yield return child;
    }
}
```

Now I can run this code:

```
foreach (var line in topics.ToOutput(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

That gives me:

```
1) TitleA
2) TitleB
3) TitleC
 3.1) TitleD
  3.1.1) TitleE
 3.2) TitleF
  3.2.1) TitleF
  3.2.2) TitleH
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly and it's structure is pretty clean and easy to read in the way I was willing for.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have *some* structure that will help with the output of the topic hierarchy, you already have it (and may even be able to simplify it more).

For example, here's an *almost*-minimal `Topic` to get what you want:

```
public class Topic
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> SubTopics { get; private set; } = new();

    public Topic() : this("DocRoot") { }

    public Topic(string title) => Title = title;

    public void AddTopics(List<Topic> subTopics) => SubTopics.AddRange(subTopics);

    public void AddTopics(params Topic[] subTopics) => SubTopics.AddRange(subTopics);

    public override string ToString() => Title;
}
```

That is, you have a `Topic` that can have `SubTopics` (aka children) and that's all you *need*.

With that, we can build your second example:

```
var firstLevelTopics = new List<Topic>();
for (var c = 'A'; c < 'D'; ++c)
{
    firstLevelTopics.Add(new Topic(c.ToString()));
}

var cTopic = firstLevelTopics.Last();
cTopic.AddTopics(
    new Topic
    {
        Title = "D",
        SubTopics = { new Topic("E") }
    },
    new Topic
    {
        Title = "F",
        SubTopics = { new Topic("G"), new Topic("H") }
    });
```

Now, imagine if we had a function to print the hierarchy from the list of top-level topics. I'm leaving the final detail for yourself in case this is homework.

```
PrintTopics(firstLevelTopics);
static void PrintTopics(List<Topic> topics, string prefix = "")
{
    // For the simple case, we can just loop and print...
    for (var i = 0; i < topics.Count; ++i)
    {
        var topic = topics[i];
        var level = i + 1;
        Console.WriteLine($"{prefix}{level}) {topic}");
        // ...but, if we want to print the children, we need more.
        // Make a recursive call to print the SubTopics
        // PrintTopics(<What goes here?>);
    }
}
```